# Batch Script Reading Information

Tags: batch-file, echo, mkdir

Kind of a long story and don't want to go to much into detail here, but when I run sciptA.bat it's giving me an error saying that these folders don't exist

scriptA.bat

```
SET /P dbLoc=<%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Data\cdLoc.txt
SET /P varNew=<%dbLoc%\db_fe_ver\versionNew.txt
SET /P varOld=<%dbLoc%\db_fe_ver\versionOld.txt
```

Am I messing up some syntax here? This was the only solution I could come up with to create a self-updating file

The "cdLoc.txt" file is being created when running a separate batch file with the following script

scriptB.bat

```
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Data\"
@echo %cd%> "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Data\cdLoc.txt"
```

After this code, it is creating a shortcut on the desktop which leads to scriptA.bat

Answer (score 0):

It was because I needed quotations

```
SET /P dbLoc=<"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Data\cdLoc.txt"
```

as there are some spaces here (deleted them for security reasons)